# Rendering 1 bit per pixel image via opengl

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glfw

Recently I've started implementing CHIP-8 emulator in C. After implementing most of the opcodes I've faced a problem of implementing display for my emulator. After some googling and reading I've decoded to give OpenGL a shot. And here's the problem - display information is stored as a 1 bit per pixel monochrome image in the last 256 bytes of CHIP-8 memory (memory is an `uint8_t` array of size 4096). Of course, I can create another array for storing display data in a more usable format (1 byte per pixel) and render it via OpenGL as a texture, but what I want to know is if there are more elegant and efficient solutions in modern OpenGL or others libraries/frameworks which can be used within the C programming language.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. English is not my mother tongue so error fixes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With modern OpenGL you can use integer textures and use a 8 bit single channel image format. Then in the shader you divide the fast running coordinate by 8 to determine the texel and the remainder to select the bit, something like this in GLSL

```
texelFetch(texture, ivec2(texcoord.x/8, texcoord.y), 0).x &
    (1 << texcoord.x%8) != 0;
```

*I'm currently on mobile, so please excuse if this is too concise. If you need more details, ask for it!*

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. I'm new to opengl and GLSL, so can you please explain in details how to process 1bpp image in GLSL or give me link to some book or article?